# Powershell downloading incomplete file using $wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)

Tags: powershell

Trying to download a .exe file from Google drive OR dropbox link through powershell. The only thing I could get to download a .exe file was the following powershell code:

```
$url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/o6jm16pkr97vbjn/sys.network.exe?dl=0"
$output = "C:\Users\Joshua\Downloads\sys.network.exe"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadFile($url, $output)
```

The original file is about 67MB. However, the file that is downloaded ends up being only 67KB. This new file does not run anymore either. What is happening, and how can I get it to download a working file? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are downloading an `exe` file, so likely your AV software is getting in the way there?